# Не удается подключиться к mssql из java-кода

Tags: java, sql-server

Добрый день.

**Вопрос в следующем:**

Есть sql server 2014. Нужно к нему подключиться из java-кода(работаю в нетбинсе).

Пытаюсь таким образом:

```
String connectionString = "Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=dbName;User id=user;Password=password;"

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
```

Сыпется исключение:

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found...

Драйвер лежит в папке lib проекта + драйвер подключаю непосредственно в коде до установления соединения:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

Если же использую строку запроса типа:

```
"jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;user=name;password=password;database=dbName"
```

То падает исключение:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection
>   to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection
>   refused: connect...

В службах сервера проверял - все порты включены со значениями 1433...

Уже закончились идеи, где копать?

Помогите, плиз.

Comment: и сервер и код на одной машине?

Comment: да,всё работает на одной машине.

Comment: Метод  `DriverManager.getConnection` всегда принимает jdbc url вида `jdbc:subprotocol:subname`. Поэтому ODBC-шная строка подключения точно не подойдет. Так что вам нужно разобраться с портом.

Comment: Выполните в консоли `netstat -a -n` и покажите строчки с портом 1433.

Comment: почему-то ни одной записи с таким портом нет...но ведь я выставил в диспетчере конфигураций везде порт 1433.получается, он всё же на другом порту работает?

Comment: после того как выставили службу рестартанули?

Comment: да, всё рестартил, службу, комп, даже из розетки на всякий случай выключил и перекрестился. но ничего.по крайней мере теперь знаю, куда копать...

Answer (score 1):

1. > java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found...

Ваша программа не видит файл с драйвером. Очевидно, положить его в папку lib недостаточно, нужно настроить вашу IDE, что бы она воспринимала эту папку должным образом. Как это сделать в Netbeans не скажу. Если вы запускаете вашу программу из командной строки, добавьте файл с драйвером в CLASSPATH.

2. > com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect...

Вы понимаете, что localhost - это ваш локальный компьютер? SQL Server установлен и запущен непосредственно на вашем локальном компьютере?

Comment: 1.когда подключаю драйвер строкой Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"); - после этого я к нему могу обратиться из кода(например, узнать версию) и всё отрабатывает норм...разве может быть так, что одна часть программы видит драйвер, а другая - нет?

Comment: 2.да, сервер на локальном компе

Comment: По поводу отсутствия драйвера может быть опечатка где-нибудь в имени. А по поводу соединения [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378672(v=sql.110).aspx) посмотрите. Мне кажется строка подключения у вас не правильная.